# Minimum bits required on a chess board

Tags: data-structures, bit-manipulation, chess

This is an interview question:

What is the minimum representation in bits of two positions on an 8x8 chessboard?

I found the answer http://www.careercup.com/question?id=4981467352399872

But I am unable to understand what the author is trying to convey when she says:

> You can represent 2^n values with n bits. However, you can represent
>   2^n + 2^(n-1) + 2^(n-2) + ... 1 = 2^(n+1) - 1   values with *atmost* n
>   bits.  So you can represent 2^11 - 1 = 2047 different values using just
>   10 bits.

I am not seeking an explanation of what the author is suggesting in his answer, but I am more interested in solving the problem itself. As far as I can think, since there are `64C2 = 2016` ways to represent two pieces on an `8x8` board, the minimum number of bits required should be 11. But someone suggested that one can use just 10 bits to represent the board. How?

Comment: The author's statement makes sense only if you consider leading zeros to be significant, that is `0110` is different from `110`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The author is saying that you can represent the positions using 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 and 10 bit values.

In binary 2016 is 11111100000 (1024 + 512+ 256 + 128 + 64 + 32)

```
5 bits  (00000 -      11111) represent 32 positions
6 bits  (000000 -     111111) represent 64 positions
7 bits  (0000000 -    1111111) represent 128 positions
8 bits  (00000000 -   11111111) represent 256 positions
9 bits  (000000000 -  111111111) represent 512 positions
10 bits (0000000000 - 1111111111) represent 1024 positions
```

A total of 2016 positions.

This could be implemented in languages with bit collections, e.g. C++ bitset, which has a size function to get the length.

Here's an example for a 2x2 board which will hopefully explain this better.

For a 2x2 board, there are 4C2 (6) positions

```
.x  x.  ..  xx  .x  x.
.x  x.  xx  ..  x.  .x
```

so you could use 3 bits 000, 001, 010, 011, 100, 101 and 110

But 6 is binary 110 (4+2) so you could use 1 bit (0-1) for 2 of the positions and 2 bits (00, 01, 10, 11) for the remaining 4. So the positions are:

0, 1, 00, 01, 10, 11.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how this works? I am unable to understand the logic. Thanks!

Comment: Of course this is rather silly, because you need to somehow encode the length, which needs more than the one bit you save.

Comment: Yes, I think it's purely an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question and receive an integer solution you must evaluation the following equation:

```
bits = ceil(log2(combination(64,2)));
bits = ceil(log2(64!/(62!*2!)));
bits = ceil(log2(64*63/2));
bits = ceil(log2(32*63));
bits = ceil(log2(32)+log2(63));
bits = ceil(5+log2(63));
bits = ceil(5+5.97728);
bits = 11;
```

Deriving the equation requires a working knowledge of [combinatorics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics).

`combination(64,2)` represents the number of ways to choose `2` of `64` possible unique spaces.